# Prove that $ \int_0^1|f(x)-x|dx\leq 1/4 $ if $ f $ is increasing on $ [0,1] $, $ 0\leq f(x)\leq 1 $ and $ \int_0^1(f(x)-x)dx=0 $.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

> Let $ f $ be an increasing function on $ [0,1] $ such that $ 0\leq f(x)\leq 1 $ and $ \int_0^1(f(x)-x)dx=0 $. Show that
> \begin{align}
> \int_0^1|f(x)-x|dx\leq 1/4.
> \end{align}

Here is my try. I find that the equality is satisfied for $ f\equiv 1/2 $. Moreover, I want to use the Poincaré inequality but I cannot bound $ \int_0^1|f'(x)-1|dx $ by $ 1/4 $. Can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: Is $f$ continuous ? Moreover, why should $f$ be derivable ?

Comment: Is the upper bound $1/4$ correct? I just wonder because here is the same question (with answers), only with $1/2$ instead of $1/4$: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3188689/42969.

Comment: @ Surb, As $ f $ is increasing, $ f' $ exists a.e.. Though it maybe inacurate, it is only my attempt, I assume that the smoothness of $ f $ and want to get some observation about it.

Comment: @MartinR, I do not find counterexample and in the question you post, I do not find the condition for the equality.

Comment: The upper bound $1/4$ is also claimed here, but without proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3190661/42969.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1. (Proof under extra assumptions)** Assume that

- $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is continuous and non-decreasing;
- $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x) - x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$;
- $f(0) = 0$, and $f(1) = 1$.

Then the set $U_+ = \{ x \in [0, 1] : f(x) > x \}$ is open, hence it is written as the union of at most countably many disjoint open intervals $(a_i, b_i)$, $i = 1, 2, \ldots $ Also, the continuity of $f$ forces that $f(b_i) = b_i$. So,

\begin{align*}
I_+ &:= \int_{U_+} |f(x) - x| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{i} \int_{(a_i, b_i)} (f(x) - x) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\leq \sum_{i} \int_{(a_i, b_i)} (b_i - x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{i} \frac{(b_i - a_i)^2}{2} \\
&\leq \frac{1}{2}\biggl( \sum_{i} (b_i - a_i) \biggr)^2
= \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Leb}(U_+)^2.
\end{align*}

A similar argument shows that, for $U_- = \{ x \in [0, 1] : f(x) < x \}$ we have

\begin{align*}
I_- := \int_{U_-} |f(x) - x| \, \mathrm{d}x 
\leq \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Leb}(U_-)^2.
\end{align*}

Moreover, from $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x) - x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$ we get $I_+ = I_-$. Therefore, together with the observations$ \int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - x| \, \mathrm{d}x = 2I_+ = 2I_-$ and $\operatorname{Leb}(U_+) + \operatorname{Leb}(U_-) \leq 1$, we conclude that

$$ \int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - x| \, \mathrm{d}x \leq \min\{ \operatorname{Leb}(U_+), \operatorname{Leb}(U_-) \}^2 \leq \frac{1}{4}. $$

These inequalities have a nice interpretation in terms of areas:

[image: figure]

**Step 2. (General case by approximation)** Now suppose $f : [0, 1] \to [0, 1]$ is non-decreasing and satisfies $\int_{0}^{1} (f(x) - x) \, \mathrm{d}x = 0$. Then it is not hard to find a sequence $f_n(x)$ satisfying the conditions in Step 1 and $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for almost every $x$. So, by the dominated convergence theorem,

$$ \int_{0}^{1} |f(x) - x| \, \mathrm{d}x
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{1} |f_n(x) - x| \, \mathrm{d}x
\leq \frac{1}{4}. $$

Comment: @MartinR, I revamped my answer. I am not fully satisfied with this as I was looking for a more elegant solution, but at least the current version faithfully reflects our geometric intuition about this problem.

Comment: This is really nice, and the image makes it clear why the inequality holds! – I wonder if $\int_{U_+} ( f(x) - x) \, dx \le \frac 12 \lambda(U_+)^2$ can somehow be proven “directly,” without resorting to continuous functions and sums first.

Comment: Is $f(0) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$ really needed in the first part of your proof?

Comment: @MartinR, Not quite, but they make both $U_{\pm}$ open sets of $\mathbb{R}$.